# JsPdf html() giving background image as black in generated pdf

Tags: javascript, jspdf, html2canvas

I am generating PDF from HTML element using `html()` of jsPDF. HTML contains background image, its getting black in generated PDF.

[CodePen Sample](https://codepen.io/chachachaudhary/pen/JjBjwpb)

**JS Code**

```
const { jsPDF } = window.jspdf;
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',downloadPdf);
function downloadPdf(){
  var doc = new jsPDF({unit:'pt'});
doc.html(document.body.querySelector('.container'), {
   callback: function (doc) {
     doc.save("sample.pdf");
   },
   html2canvas:{scale:.4},
   x: 10,
   y: 10
});
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="txtbox bgimg">
    Title goes here
    </div>
</div>
<button>Download PDF</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.container{
  height:200px; 
  background-image:url("https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif")
}
.txtbox{
  color:Blue;
  font-size:36px;
  text-align:center;
  }
```